# Ionic 5 + Electron

Tags: electron, ionic5

I'm trying to start an Electron project, but running `ionic capacitor run electron` results in a blank screen with 5 console errors that say `GET file:///c:/runtime.js net:ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.

I'm pretty sure it has to do with `<base href="/">` needing to be changed to `<base href="./">` but I can't get the change to stick.

If I manually change the base tag in `/www/index.html` then run `ionic capacitor run electron` the value in `<base>` is automatically changed back to the default.

What's the correct way to make the change stick so I can build an Electron app?
Steps to reproduce:

```
1. ionic start test blank --capacitor --type angular
2. cd test
3. open `/tsconfig.json` and change `target` from `es2015` to `es5`
4. ionic build
5. open `/www/index.html` and change `<base href="/">` to <base href="./">`
6. ionic cap add electron
7. ionic cap run electron
```

Step 7 is where `<base>` gets overwritten again because I see run `app:build` listed in the terminal... Any advice on how to get it to work as expected? I imagine there is a better method than manually changing code because that seems tedious in a production app

Comment: have you checked your platform with 'npx cap doctor electron' ?

Comment: the electron platform is deprecated

Answer (score 2):

just wondered if you still have this problem?

If yes, try running `npx cap copy` after every build to sync the web content with Electron.

Moreover, you can also change the base tag in `/src/index.html` so you don't need to update it in `/www/index.html` after every build.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled across this question. This is a workflow that has worked ok for me. Also includes the npm package [electron-packager](https://github.com/electron/electron-packager) which helps bundle the electron output to distributable binaries.

package.json:

```json
{
  // ...

  "scripts": {
    // ...
 
    "package:electron:windows": "electron-packager ./electron MyApp --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --out=./release --overwrite",
    "package:electron:macos": "electron-packager ./electron MyApp --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --out=./release --overwrite",
    "build:electron": "ng build --base-href ./ && ionic cap sync electron --no-build",
    "build:electron:windows": "npm run build:electron && npm run package:electron:windows",
    "build:electron:macos": "npm run build:electron && npm run package:electron:macos"
  }
  
  // ...
}
```

So then with one command line `npm run build:electron:windows` or `npm run build:electron:macos` it will create the distributable in a folder called `release`

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch steps 4 & 5.
I mean, first change the `index.html` (step 5) and then execute `ionic build` (step 4).